# Submitting form values to a JS array object rather than to an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Been working on this issue for a while now and I just cant get my head around it. There are a few similar answers but nothing that seems to tackle my exact issue.

So I have a form. The values from this are all going to be numbers. I want to capture the values inside an array to perform calculations on them before sending a seperate AJAX call with the new variables. Im really surprised at how hard this seems to be to get working.

My code should be outputting the values of the form into key/value pairs within array x, however this array just seems to be empty (contains `{object Object}` pairs for every form name/value pair.

Any ideas? If there is a better method to achieving this, i'm all ears (or eyes, whatever!). I guess an easy way would be to just bind this to a click rather than submit event, but I dont want to lose all the other user form submission abilities (pressing enter etc).

Javascript:

```
$('#zombieForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var x = $(":input").serializeArray();
    alert(x); //currently using a sandbox without console for this
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="zombieForm" method="post">
    <select name="multi2" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="100">placeholder value 4</option>
        <option value="50">placeholder value 3</option>
        <option value="25">placeholder value 2</option>
        <option value="0">placeholder value 1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="formButton" />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `event.preventDefault()` before the rest of the block?

Comment: For your event listener, you need to target $('#zombieForm') instead of $('zombieForm')

Comment: @wilbur Just tried that, it still just POSTs back to the source URL (kinda glad actually, if that fixed it I would have had to bang my head against the wall!)

Comment: @Maverick976 yeah that was a typo on my part. So yes putting event.preventDefault() at top prevents post, however array is still blank, just contains {object Object} pairs

Comment: Just updated the question with your input

Comment: Have you included jQuery? Using your example [I cannot reproduce the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/vs6ze0uv/).

Comment: @AshleyHowe "... just contains {object Object} pairs"? But you know that `serializeArray` indeed produces an array of {object Object} with `name` and `value` elements? So it is not "blank", but seems to work as designed. The result ist just in the form as promised by jQuery, which is not the form that you expect.

Comment: @rplantiko I think its quite possible i misunderstood the serializeArray method in that case :s. I thought it returned the form values and names as strings to an array. How would i convert the objects to strings? (this is probably a very basic question, ive only really used arrays for numbers and strings before)

Comment: You have to iterate over the result of `serializeArray` and to turn each array element into a member of a hash, as you seem to expect. This is precisely the solution proposed by @Maverick976 below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.  Is this what you're after? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hu2ef15v/)

```
$('#zombieForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var yourArray = {};
    $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function() {
        yourArray[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    console.log(yourArray);
});
```

Comment: I cant get your fiddle working, tried it in codepen with an alert instead of a console.log and i'm just getting {object Object} again.. is this working on yours?

Comment: It's `{object Object}`, yes, but this object should have all the form names as properties (and the values as values of these properties)

Comment: Sorry i'm really not getting this, would you mind breaking down how this function works and how I would return a string value from this array?

Comment: @Ash Essentially this creates a new associative array from the serialized array.  It goes through each form element that has been serialized, creating a key (this.name) and value (this.value) inside the new associative array.  If you check my fiddle and open your developer console, you'll see the array logged once you submit the form.

Comment: @Ash if you want to return a string value from the array, access it using `yourArray['key']` for the value that you want, the 'key' being the name of the form element (in this case, multi2).

Comment: @Maverick976 thanks maverick that makes sense. Sorry for the confusion, totally misunderstood what the .serializeArray method was doing. This explanation should be useful to others though, there were a few other questions of this type that didnt seem to have clear answers